# Read more read less span with dynamic id to loop through

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I created a read more/read less using javscript and html. The read more/less is under looped posts however it only works for the first post and the other posts only have the button readmore which is not working. what can i do to the javascript for it to work.

### blade file

```
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
  
{{$post->about}}

                                 <div class="group-four">
                                      <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn"> more info </button>
                                      <p><span id="dots"></span><span id="more"> dfsafjklllllllllllfffffffffa </span></p>

                                  
                                </div>


@endforeach
```

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
      moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
      moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
  </script>
```

### blade file new

```
 <div class="group-four">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn"> more info </button>
       <p><span id="dots"></span><span id="{{$post->id}}"> 
          dfsafjklllllllllllfffffffffa </span></p>

                                  
  </div>
```

### new script

```js
<script>
 read = '<?php echo $pick_more ;?>';



  function myFunction() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById(read);
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
      moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
      moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: You're creating multiple posts with multiple buttons with multiple more texts... But all of them are accessed through an id?

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani yes they are accessed through an id

Comment: You're telling through your code "select THE dots with this id"... "Select THE more text with this id"... "Select THE button with this id". But you may have hundreds of them.

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani i think i have some direction now let me try to  work on it

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani using id of the post would only work with the last id. i believe its because it is the only value existing in the variable when the loop is done. i tried using an array but i can't assign an array to a id.  could there be a way out for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Problem**]
The problem is that you're looping over the posts, adding the HTML elements for them, and you want to call a function for each of them and want to perform some tasks for those particular elements only. BUT for each of the posts you're keeping the id for those HTML elements the same.

[**SOLUTION**]
Your span, the button should have unique ids for every post, so that you can get the span for a particular post and perform some task on it. For that, you can pass the id of the post to the `myFunction` as an argument

And in `myFunction($id)` you receive the id of the post, get the span, and everything using that post's id and perform the task only to that element(which is specific to your post)

[CODE]

Change your div element to this

```
<div class="group-four">
  <button onclick="<?= 'myFunction(' . $post->id . ')' ?>" id="<?= 'myBtn_' . $post->id ?>" > more info </button>
  <p>
      <span id="<?= 'dots_' . $post->id ?>">
      </span>
      <span id="<?= 'more_' . $post->id ?>">
         dfsafjklllllllllllfffffffffa
      </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

And script to

```
function myFunction(id) {

   var dots = document.getElementById("dots_" + id);
   var moreText = document.getElementById("more_"+id);
   var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn_"+id);

.....
}
```